# "How does he get on at school?" instead of "How is getting on at school"?

Tags: present-tense

Is the sentence "How does he do at school?" and "How does he get on at school?" correct and can be used instead of "How is he doing and getting on at school?" if we are talking about it generally?

Comment: I'd say *How is getting on at school?* is the "default" phrasing, covering ***all*** aspects of his schooling (social as well as academic). *How is **doing** at school?* would often be equivalent, but to me that one focuses slightly more on his *academic* performance. The "do-support" version strikes me as slightly "marked", so it would only be likely in certain "peculiar" contexts. For example, if you'd just been talking about how the boy was getting on ***at home***, you might reasonably broaden the scope of the discussion by asking ***How does he get on at school**?*

Comment: And broading the scope of the discussion by asking again in the progressive "how is he getting on at school?" would be more natural. Right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the missing subjects in first comment - obviously it's *How is **he** getting on at school?* Note that not everyone would necessarily make even the slightest distinction between that version and *How is he **doing** at school?* But I personally see "how he's getting on" as primarily asking about *[externally measured] **performance***, whereas "how he's doing" focuses more on *[internally experienced] **reactions / feelings*** (whether he's ***happy*** at school, for example).

Comment: No worries! Thank you : )